# What address to use on K-ETA if I want to visit Seoul during a long layover

Tags: layovers, k-eta

I will have a long layover on Incheon.  I want to visit Seoul during this layover, but [according the official website](https://k-eta.go.kr/portal/board/viewboardlist.do?tmpltNm=faq) I need a K-ETA and I need to write the address where I'll be staying.

> Q17: Transfer/transit passengers who are not entering Korea do not need to get a K-ETA.

> Q40: please enter the address of main location where you will be staying during the visit. If the address is changed after you obtained the K-ETA approval, please update it at the K-ETA website [K-ETA Application Results]-[Edit Information]. Please be advised that there may be disadvantages if you do not update your address.

Since my visit will be a short one, I will not get a hotel room.  What should I put as the address in this case?

Comment: In these cases I typically write "transit" in the form. I don't know whether this is acceptable for South Korea or not. If that doesn't work just book the cheapest hostel and use their address. It's less than US$10 per night

Answer (score 5):

If you are spending the majority of time (at any one place) at the airport maybe try just writing the address of the  airport eg. 272, Gonghang-ro, Jung-gu, Incheon, 22382 Korea.

The [FAQ Q40](https://www.k-eta.go.kr/portal/board/viewboardlist.do?bbsId=12&tmpltNm=faq) says to give the address of the "main location", so it is defensible.

[image]